# How can I start docky?

Tags: 12.04, docky, xubuntu

how can I start docky? When I open it, nothing happens. When I open it in a terminal it just says:

[Info  08:25:58.751] Docky version: 2.1.4 Release
[Info  08:25:58.760] Kernel version: 3.2.0.24
[Info  08:25:58.763] CLR version: 4.0.30319.1

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Hello, I have the exact same problem after upgrading from xubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, these messages appear in the console, but I can't see the docky window. The same thing happens on the version from ubuntu repositores and when I compile it from the latest source. Did you get this to work?

Comment: I managed to start it after restarting XFCE. From what I can tell the reason why it didn't start is because I started `dbus-launch cmus` before `startx` and I'm not sure, but I guess that was the reason...

Comment: Might help to do a `ps aux | grep docky` and make sure it's running (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay,let's take everything from start:

Install docky using  `sudo apt-get install docky` typed in terminal.

Run by typing `docky` or via Accessories->Docky,which will give you as start of the output the text that you typed,but thats not all.

Make sure you have the latest libraries that must be installed to run docky(as found at the official docky site):

```
* bzr (>= 0.92)
* dbus-sharp-1.0
* dbus-sharp-glib-1.0
* gconf-2.0
* gconf-sharp-2.0
* gconftool-2
* gdk-2.0
* gdk-x11-2.0
* gio-sharp-2.0
* glib-2.0
* glib-sharp-2.0
* gobject-2.0
* gtk+-2.0
* gtk-sharp-2.0
* gnome-desktop-sharp-2.0
* gnome-keyring-sharp-1.0
* mono-addins, mono-addins-gui, mono-addins-setup
* mono-cairo
* notify-sharp
* libtool
* mono-gmcs
* rsvg-sharp-2.0
* wnck-sharp-1.0
```

Then you should be able to run the program.